# How to install Kinect for Windows on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kinect

I tried to look up from the internet to find the method to install kinect on my Ubuntu. The beginning was successful but when i reached this part:

$ ./RedistMaker

It showed Building failed and then I couldn't proceed to the next step.

Anyone has any idea regarding this problem or any alternative way to install Kinect on Ubuntu 18.04? TQ.

Answer (score 0):

I know a project that has not been updated for a while, but maybe it can work, I think it depends on the version of Ubuntu you use.

This is the project page where you can find the sources: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/

And this is the Wiki that will help you install it: https://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page